# MVVM WPF Multibinding is not working for command parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command, multibinding

I cannot make multibinding working for two passwordbox. I did read a bunch of articles on the net tried working examples, but none of them was the same scenario that I've tried. The problem is when I hit the login button then these password fields are not transfered to the command Execute method.

XAML for the converter:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <converter:PasswordConverter x:Key="passwordConverter"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

XAML for the button looks like this:

```
<Button x:Name="loginButton" 
                Content="Belépés" 
                Margin="494,430,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                FontSize="20" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="-2.624,8.99" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Width="172"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}">
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource passwordConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding Path="Password" ElementName="userIDPasswordBox"/>
                    <Binding Path="Password" ElementName="leaderIDPasswordBox"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
```

Password converter code:

```
public class PasswordConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Clone();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Relay command:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{

    Action _TargetExecuteMethod;
    Func<bool> _TargetCanExecuteMethod;

    public RelayCommand(Action executeMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
        _TargetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {

        if (_TargetCanExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return _TargetCanExecuteMethod();
        }

        if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            _TargetExecuteMethod();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and last huge piece of code for the view model:

```
public class LogonViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

private Action _loginActionComplete;
public LogonViewModel(Action loginActionComplete)
{
    _measureTimer = new Timer();
    _measureTimer.Interval = 500D;
    _measureTimer.Elapsed += measureTimer_Elapsed;
    _measureTimer.Start();
    _loginActionComplete = loginActionComplete;
    NavCommand = new RelayCommand(loginActionComplete);
    SerialPort = new SerailCommunicationNameSpace.SerialCommunication("COM3");
}

~LogonViewModel()
{
    SerialPort.Close();
}

public RelayCommand NavCommand { get; private set; }

private double _measuredWeight;
public double MeasuredWeight {
    get
    {
        return _measuredWeight;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _measuredWeight, value);
    }
}
private Timer _measureTimer;
public SerailCommunicationNameSpace.SerialCommunication SerialPort { get; set; }

private void measureTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var measuredWeight = 0D;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SerialPort.DataReceived) == false) {
        var dataReceivedStartTrim = SerialPort.DataReceived.TrimStart();
        var dataReceivedNumbersOnly = dataReceivedStartTrim.Substring(0, dataReceivedStartTrim.IndexOf(' '));
        var enUSCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        measuredWeight = double.Parse(dataReceivedNumbersOnly, enUSCultureInfo);
    }
    SetProperty(ref _measuredWeight, measuredWeight);
    OnPropertyChanged("MeasuredWeight");
}

public string LeaderId { get; set; }

public string UserId { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: Your RelayCommand implementation does not pass the `object parameter` from the Execute method to the `_TargetExecuteMethod` Action. Obviously, you need a different implementation.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! :) the execute method still not receiving any values. Both password is set on the UI, but empty string is what the command is seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Password` property of `PasswordBox` is neither a dependency property nor implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This means, that the changes of password will not be applied to the binding.
E.g. if you add an event handler for `PasswordChanged` to the `PasswordBox` and set the password to the `Tag` property, then you can bind to the `Tag` and the binding will work.

```
<Button x:Name="loginButton" 
        Content="Belépés" 
        Margin="494,430,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        FontSize="20" 
        RenderTransformOrigin="-2.624,8.99" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Width="172"
        Command="{Binding NavCommand}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource passwordConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Tag" ElementName="userIDPasswordBox"/>
            <Binding Path="Tag" ElementName="leaderIDPasswordBox"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>

<PasswordBox Name="userIDPasswordBox" PasswordChanged="PasswordBox_PasswordChanged"/>
<PasswordBox Name="leaderIDPasswordBox" PasswordChanged="PasswordBox_PasswordChanged"/>

private void PasswordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pbx = sender as PasswordBox;
    if (pbx!=null)
    {
        pbx.Tag = pbx.Password;
    }
}
```

Of course to avoid code behind implementation you should move the event handler to the behavior.